# display result of an if statement in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, textbox

I have a list of films from A-Z that i want to watch , im trying to make a program to pick a letter from a-z and then display the name of the corresponding movie in a textbox , could anyone help , als some tips on expanding the program to make it even better would be great

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function randomString() {
                var chars = "1B";
                var string_length = 1;
                var randomstring = '';

                var movie = document.getElementById('movie');

                for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
                    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
                    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
                }
                document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;


                if (i === 1) {
                    movie = "13 Assassins";
                }
                else
                if (i === A) {
                    movie = "Apollo 13";
                }




            }
        </script>

        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="center_page">
            <div id="maincontent">
                <section id="topcontent">
                    <form name="randform">
                        <input type="button" value="Pick a random movie"   onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
                        <input type="text" name="randomfield" value="">
                        <input type="text" name="movie" id="movie" readonly>

                    </form>

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post any code that you have top this point?

Comment: ye , just editing it now , trying to indent 4 spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ...

```
var movies = [
  "A Movie",
  "B Movie",
  ...
];

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length);
var movieString = movies[rand];
var randomString = movies[rand][1];
document.getElementById('movie').innerHTML = movies[rand];
document.randform.randomfield.value = randomString;
```

Basically, if you have a list of movies from A-Z in the array above, this code will get a random movie from the list (ragardless of length), as well as assign the first character ("starts with") to use as `randomString`.  The movie title will be placed into the `#movie` element (assuming textbox).

Working code here ... **http://jsbin.com/cogume/2/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: i was trying to display the variable movie in a textbox , the variable movie would depend on the result of the random generator, have you got any idea on how to do this

Comment: Updated ... unless I have completely misunderstood the question, this should work.

Comment: Works on mine ... remember to replace the list of movies and remove the "..."  In the demo, refresh to see the textarea update.